Is there a simple way to open an authenticator app for viewing?
I know how to open an authenticator app for registering a new account by using the URL scheme
otpauth://...
But what if I simply want to open the authenticator app for viewing? For example, I want to add a "Open authenticator app" button to the 2FA auth page in my app, which would make it more convenient for the user to open their 2FA app and copy the auth code, than manually opening it from the launcher/home screen/etc.
I know what you're thinking - this would only work if the user has their 2FA app on the same device as my app. But honestly, that probably applies to 99.9999% of all users...
And yes, I know what you're thinking again - I can fiddle around with Android-intents and iOS-whatnots. But surely the authors of authenticator apps must have come up with a simpler way, like an otpauth://... URI that simply opens the app for viewing?
otpauth://
otpauth://totp
otpauth://totp/foobar

If I try to launch any of these URI's, some authnticator apps (like Google Authenticator), complain that "the QR code is invalid". So it seems that they only expect the otpauth scheme to be used for registering via QR code.
I've seen this question asked a few times before, and it always turns out to be misunderstood by the people answering it. So to make it perfectly clear - I know how to create the URI and QR code that is used for registering a new 2FA account. That's not what I'm asking. I want to launch the authenticator app, or a chooser if the user has more than one authenticator app installed, for viewing (the 2FA TOTP codes).
